# Print duplicate items which have the same property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I get items duplicate properties and push it in the object?

For example I have:

```
var object = { "1" :{"ip": 4},  "2" :{"ip": 3}, "3" :{"ip": 4}, "4" :{"ip": 3}}
```

I expect to have an object or array where I will have `[[1,3], [2,4]]`

Comment: Could you please give a valid expected output?

Comment: Did you mean `{[1,3], [2,4]}` or `{"4":[1,3], "3": [2,4]}`

Comment: @gurvinder372 the output should be first one all items which have the same properties separate

Comment: So `[[1,3], [2,4]]` ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect to have an object or array where I will have {[1,3], [2,4]}

If you meant `[[1,3], [2,4]]`, then use `reduce` and `Object.values`

**Demo**

```js
var object = { "1" :{"ip": 4},  "2" :{"ip": 3}, "3" :{"ip": 4}, "4" :{"ip": 3}};

var output = Object.values(Object.keys( object ).reduce( function( a, b){
   var key = object[ b ].ip; //key to be used for grouping the values
   a[ key ] = a[ key ] || [];
   a[ key ].push( Number(b) );
   return a;
} ,{}));

console.log( output.reverse() );
```

Comment: but if I want to have [{1,3}, {2,4}]?

Comment: @Radharu Fixed it.

Comment: does not see it, not fixed yet)

Comment: @Radharu Ah, missed number conversion. Check now

Comment: no, not fixed, please check by yourself) it does not give array of objects

Comment: Why would it give array of objects?

Comment: I need array of objects as I mentioned above  [{1,3}, {2,4}] :)

Comment: Please read the comments again. Your expected output is invalid object.

Comment: ok thanks, but if it is possible I wanted to have it)array of objects

Comment: @Radharu Objects have key and value. `[{1,3}, {2,4}]` is an invalid object structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` and ES6 `Map` and return array of arrays.

```js
var object = { "1" :{"ip": 4},  "2" :{"ip": 3}, "3" :{"ip": 4}, "4" :{"ip": 3}}

var result = [...Object.keys(object).reduce((r, e) => {
  let ip = object[e].ip
  if(!r.get(ip)) r.set(ip, [e]);
  else r.get(ip).push(e);
  return r;
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why are you using `Map` here? is it about performance? why not to do it as it was done by @gurvinder372?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` and `JSON.stringify` the values as key and add the key which have the same values.

```js
var object = { "1" :{"ip": 4},  "2" :{"ip": 3}, "3" :{"ip": 4}, "4" :{"ip": 3}};

var result = Object.keys(object).reduce((map,key) => {
  var k = JSON.stringify(object[key]);
  map[k] =  map[k] || [];
  map[k].push(key);
  return map;
},{});
var output = Object.values(result);
console.log(output);
```